# Credit card fields showing under PayPal Express Checkout

Tags: magento, paypal, credit-card

I'm using Magento 2.3
I have noticed on my website that credit card fields are showing under the PayPal express checkout option but this wasn't the case before.

[image]

It didn't appear this way before and I've checked the backend of our Magento2 site to turn the fields off but there isn't an option for this. But when I disable the paypal express checkout, they are all disappeared.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!